# Chrome storage responds undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have following function to make reading data from chrome storage easy:

```
function readExtensionStorage(key, callback) {
var myKey = key;
callback(chrome.storage.local.get(myKey, function (items) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
        if (JSON.stringify(items) == "{}")
            callback(null);
        else
            callback(items);
    }
}));
```

}

I'm using the function like following:

```
readExtensionStorage(proxyName, function (value) {
         console.log(value);
     });
```

But it responds two time and the first one always undefined. What am i doing false? I have a output like this:

```
undefined
[Object]
```

Comment: Because your calling the callback twice. Why are you wrapping `chrome.storage.local.get`?

Comment: great thanks!

i removed the first callback, it works now.